# How to go about creating XLS file (Matlab/HTML/JS)?

Tags: html, matlab

I have been using MATLAB to ask plenty of questions via questdlg and then saving all the answers as `data = {'Name of variable1', 'Name of variable2', etc}`. I am on a MAC so `xlswrite` does not work. I have used `xlwrite` and it works when I hit run in MATLAB. I have compiled this via the Application compiler and included the `xlwrite` file. When running the file, the questions are asked, but the file is not created. This is a little odd as it works and creates the file in MATLAB directly.

I switched to `dlmcell` and this works in MATLAB but not when run externally. As this needs to run on Windows and MAC I would have to use `dlmcell`? (testing on mac, then distributing on mac and windows).

What I am trying to find out, is why would it work in MATLAB but not when compiled? If this is a big problem, then I thought HTML would be a good choice. Can I write data to .txt/.xls via HTML?

```
prompt = {'Enter serial number'};
dlg_title = 'Serial Number';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {'15'};
Serial_Number = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);    
SN = char(Serial_Number) %ANSWER%
prompt = {'Enter your name'};
dlg_title = 'Your name';  
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = {''};
Name = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);   
User = char(Name) %ANSWER%

%%PREPERATION%%
LicensePI = 'Which license is installed?'; %QUESTION%
set(0,'DefaultImageVisible','off') %Disables icon
LicensePIAns = questdlg('Which license is installed?', 'Preperation', 'Basic', 'Medium','Advanced'); %ANSWER%

LicenseGen = 'Which type of temporary license was preferred?'; %QUESTION%
LicensGenAns = questdlg('Which type of temporary license was preferred?', 'Basic', 'Medium', 'Advanced'); %ANSWER%
%%PREPERATION%%

filename = 'Test.xls';
data = {SN, User, LicensePI, LicensePIAns, LicenseGen, LicensGenAns}
dlmcell('sat.txt',data);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. That way we can see what's going on and try to help you.

Comment: I have added my code